# Styling Duo drawer navigation menu in android

Tags: android, navigation-drawer

I am doing an android project where I am using Duo Navigation Drawer. I am unable to change the menu style. I want to change the font type and remove bullets from the list please see the below image

[image]

Below is my Main Activity

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements DuoMenuView.OnMenuClickListener{

    private MenuAdapter mMenuAdapter;
    private ViewHolder mViewHolder;
    boolean clickAgainToExit = false;
    Typeface custom_font;

    private ArrayList<String> mTitles = new ArrayList();
    private ArrayList<Integer> mTitlesIcon = new ArrayList();

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        this.custom_font = AppUtils.getTypefaceblack(this);
        SetupDrawer();
    }

     private void SetupDrawer() {

        this.mTitles = new ArrayList(Arrays.asList(getResources().getStringArray(R.array.menuOptions)));

        this.mTitlesIcon = new ArrayList();
         this.mTitlesIcon.add(R.drawable.home);
        this.mTitlesIcon.add(R.drawable.add_bussiness);
        this.mTitlesIcon.add(R.drawable.news);
        this.mTitlesIcon.add(R.drawable.setting);
        this.mTitlesIcon.add(R.drawable.share_icon);

         // Initialize the views
        mViewHolder = new ViewHolder();

        // Handle toolbar actions
        handleToolbar();

        // Handle menu actions
        handleMenu();

        // Handle drawer actions
        handleDrawer();

        // Show main fragment in container
        goToFragment(new MainFragment(), false);
        this.mMenuAdapter.setViewSelected(0, true);
        setTitle(mTitles.get(0));

         View headerView = mViewHolder.mDuoMenuView.getHeaderView();

         TextView textView = (TextView) headerView.findViewById(R.id.user_name);
         textView.setTypeface(this.custom_font);
         TextView textView2 = (TextView) headerView.findViewById(R.id.app_name);
         textView2.setTypeface(this.custom_font);
         TextView textView3 = (TextView) headerView.findViewById(R.id.tvlocation);
         textView3.setSelected(true);
    }

    private void handleToolbar() {
        setSupportActionBar(mViewHolder.mToolbar);
    }

    private void handleDrawer() {
        DuoDrawerToggle duoDrawerToggle = new DuoDrawerToggle(this,
                mViewHolder.mDuoDrawerLayout,
                mViewHolder.mToolbar,
                R.string.navigation_drawer_open,
                R.string.navigation_drawer_close);

        mViewHolder.mDuoDrawerLayout.setDrawerListener(duoDrawerToggle);
        duoDrawerToggle.syncState();

    }

    private void handleMenu() {
        this.mMenuAdapter = new MenuAdapter(this.mTitles,this.mTitlesIcon);

        mViewHolder.mDuoMenuView.setOnMenuClickListener(this);
        mViewHolder.mDuoMenuView.setAdapter(mMenuAdapter);
    }

    @Override
    public void onFooterClicked() {
        Toast.makeText(this, "onFooterClicked", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }

    @Override
    public void onHeaderClicked() {
        Toast.makeText(this, "onHeaderClicked", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }

    private void goToFragment(Fragment fragment, boolean addToBackStack) {
        FragmentTransaction transaction = getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();

        if (addToBackStack) {
            transaction.addToBackStack(null);
        }

        transaction.add(R.id.container, fragment).commit();
    }

    @Override
    public void onOptionClicked(int position, Object objectClicked) {
        // Set the toolbar title
        setTitle(mTitles.get(position));

        // Set the right options selected
        mMenuAdapter.setViewSelected(position, true);

        // Navigate to the right fragment
        switch (position) {
//            default:
//                goToFragment(new MainFragment(), false);
//                break;

            case 0:
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"Home",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                break;
            case 1:
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"Personal",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                break;
            case 2:
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"News",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                break;
            case 3:
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"Settings",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                break;
            case 4:
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"About",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                break;
        }

        // Close the drawer
        mViewHolder.mDuoDrawerLayout.closeDrawer();
    }

    private class ViewHolder {
        private DuoDrawerLayout mDuoDrawerLayout;
        private DuoMenuView mDuoMenuView;
        private Toolbar mToolbar;

        ViewHolder() {
            mDuoDrawerLayout = findViewById(R.id.drawer);
            mDuoMenuView = (DuoMenuView) mDuoDrawerLayout.getMenuView();
            mToolbar = findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
        }
    }
}
```

and below is my menuAdapter

```
class MenuAdapter extends BaseAdapter {

    private ArrayList<View> mOptionViews = new ArrayList();
    private ArrayList<String> mOptions = new ArrayList();
    private ArrayList<Integer> mTitlesIcon = new ArrayList();

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int i) {
        return i;
    }

    public MenuAdapter(ArrayList<String> menuoptions, ArrayList<Integer> menuicons) {
        this.mOptions = menuoptions;
        this.mTitlesIcon = menuicons;
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return this.mOptions.size();
    }

    @Override
    public Object getItem(int position) {
        return this.mOptions.get(position);
    }

    void setViewSelected(int position, boolean selected) {

        for (int i = 0; i < this.mOptionViews.size(); i++) {
            if (i == position) {
                ((DuoOptionView) this.mOptionViews.get(i)).setSelected(selected);
            } else {
                ((DuoOptionView) this.mOptionViews.get(i)).setSelected(!selected);
            }
        }
    }


    @Override
    public View getView(int i, View view, ViewGroup viewGroup) {
        String str = (String) this.mOptions.get(i);

        i =((Integer) this.mTitlesIcon.get(i)).intValue();

        if(view == null){
            view = new DuoOptionView(viewGroup.getContext());
        }else{
            view = (DuoOptionView) view;
        }

        ((DuoOptionView) view).bind(str,i);
        this.mOptionViews.add(view);
        return view;
    }
}
```

How to change recertify this. please suggest me.

I took this from [link](https://github.com/PSD-Company/duo-navigation-drawer)

Comment: Asesha have you got any solution to your problem???

Comment: @Wini yes i could able to change the icons.

Comment: Asesha then can you put up your whole solution here ?

Answer (score 1):

Sorry for the late reply, but I think this code will help you to get every item in navigation menu view to change text color or typeface.

In `getView` method you should make change to child view as you want:

```
(((TextView)((RelativeLayout)((RelativeLayout)optionView.getChildAt(0)).getChildAt(1)).getChildAt(1))).setTextColor(Color.BLACK);
```

full code of method like :

```
@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    final String option = mOptions.get(position);
    // Using the DuoOptionView to easily recreate the demo
    final DuoOptionView optionView;
    if (convertView == null) {
        optionView = new DuoOptionView(parent.getContext());
        optionView.getChildAt(0);
    } else {
        optionView = (DuoOptionView) convertView;


    }
    (((TextView)((RelativeLayout)((RelativeLayout)optionView.getChildAt(0)).getChildAt(1)).getChildAt(1))).setTextColor(Color.BLACK);
    // Using the DuoOptionView's default selectors
    optionView.bind(option, null, null);
    // Adding the views to an array list to handle view selection
    mOptionViews.add(optionView);

    return optionView;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

To change icon on drawer items, you can use something similar to below:

```
optionView.bind(option, getDrawable(R.drawable.ic_icon), null);
```

**Note:** Above will set same icon to all drawer items. You need to use `TypedArray` with list of icons...

Answer (score 0):

Solution 1. In your MenuAdapter Change

```
@Override
public View getView(int i, View view, ViewGroup viewGroup) {
    String str = (String) this.mOptions.get(i);

    i =((Integer) this.mTitlesIcon.get(i)).intValue();

    if(view == null){
        view = new DuoOptionView(viewGroup.getContext());
    }else{
        view = (DuoOptionView) view;
    }

    ((DuoOptionView) view).bind(str,i);
    this.mOptionViews.add(view);
    return view;
}
```

with

```
@Override
public View getView(int i, View view, ViewGroup viewGroup) {
    String str = (String) this.mOptions.get(i);

    i =((Integer) this.mTitlesIcon.get(i)).intValue();

    if(view == null){
        view = new DuoOptionView(viewGroup.getContext());
    }else{
        view = (DuoOptionView) view;
    }

    ((DuoOptionView) view).bind(str); // change is here
    this.mOptionViews.add(view);
    return view;
}
```

Solution  2. 
or you can set drawable like this

```
 // Using the DuoOptionView's default selectors
 optionView.bind(option, ContextCompat.getDrawable(context,
 android.R.drawable.ic_dialog_alert), null);
```

[image]

solution 3. or if you have source code if the library the set visibility to gone for mOptionViewHolder.mImageViewSelector.setVisibility(GONE);

see attached image i have same way
[image]

Answer (score 0):

Step 1. In MainActivity.java change method handleMenu()

> ```
> private void handleMenu() {
>         mMenuAdapter = new MenuAdapter(mTitles, mTitlesIcon, this); //pass context
>         mViewHolder.mDuoMenuView.setOnMenuClickListener(this);
>         mViewHolder.mDuoMenuView.setAdapter(mMenuAdapter);
>          }
> ```

Step 2. In MenuAdapter.java

```
  private Context mContext;

 public MenuAdapter(ArrayList<String> menuoptions, ArrayList<Integer>
 menuicons, Context context) {
         this.mOptions = menuoptions;
         this.mTitlesIcon = menuicons;
        this.mContext = context;
     }
```

Step 3. In MenuAdapter.java

```
@Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        final String option = mOptions.get(position);
        //Log.d("TAG", position+";");
     
        final DuoOptionView optionView;
        if (convertView == null) {
            optionView = new DuoOptionView(parent.getContext());
            optionView.getChildAt(0);
        } else {
            optionView = (DuoOptionView) convertView;
        }
        optionView.bind(option, context.getResources().getDrawable(mTitlesIcon.get(position)));
        // Adding the views to an array list to handle view selection
        mOptionViews.add(optionView);
        return optionView;
    }
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IFZc2.jpg)

Answer (score 0):

To remove the bullets just add `optionView.setSelectorEnabled(false);` in the MenuAdapter in the getView method.

```
@Override
    public View getView(int i, View view, ViewGroup viewGroup) {
        String str = (String) this.mOptions.get(i);

        i =((Integer) this.mTitlesIcon.get(i)).intValue();

        if(view == null){
            view = new DuoOptionView(viewGroup.getContext());
        }else{
            view = (DuoOptionView) view;
        }
        optionView.setSelectorEnabled(false);

        ((DuoOptionView) view).bind(str,i);
        this.mOptionViews.add(view);
        return view;
    }
```